# How to get the database instance and schema details of Oracle , SQL Server, postgres, mysql or any other database using C#?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, postgresql

I need to get the details of databases installed in a machine using c#. For eg: the database instance and schema details of oracle, PostgreSQL , sql server,mysql etc. Any suggestions.

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA. ...` tables

Answer (score 0):

You can use getSchema method
[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254934(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: the above link is used to retrieve schema information about the database that is currently connected. I need to get the details of all the database instances in the current machine